# Linking problems with storage class defined as static

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, static, linker

On the .dll file

```
//SWC.h

#ifndef _SWC_
#    define _SWC_
#    define SWC_CALL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define SWC_CALL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace SWC
{

    struct SWC_CALL Mouse
    {
        //interface
    };

    class SWC_CALL SWC_Base : public someClass1, public someClass2
    {

        static Mouse mouse;

    };

    //other classes goes here...
}

//SWC_Base.cpp
namespace SWC
{

    Mouse SWC_Base::mouse; //needed, to compile

    //other SWC_Base function definition

}
```

On .exe file

with the `static struct Mouse mouse` I defined on the `SWC_Base` I get linking errors

I solve my problem by redefining it again on this file

```
//main.cpp

#include "SWC.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "..\\SWC")

SWC::Mouse SWC::SWC_Base::mouse; //<- why do I need to redefine it again?

int main()
{
    //...

    return 0;

}
```

I already define the SWC_Base::mouse on its .cpp file, why do I need to redefine it again on the file who uses it? I know I can have this more problems as my .dll project is growing with static variables on it.

Comment: But do you _link_ with `SWC_Base.cpp`?

Comment: yes, except that `mouse` get me linking problems. Took me a day to figure it out.

Comment: This isn't the actual code. I wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @harper it is a thousand lines of codes. Do everyone will get interested if I put it here.

Comment: You had a comment on a now deleted answer that you "link it properly using macros". What do you mean by that? Macros is a preprocessor thing and has nothing to do with the linker. Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and show us.

Comment: okay, I am apologizing for the words I misused. Sorry for that cause English is not our primary language.

Comment: @mr5 Nobody is interested in reading your complete code. But there is a concept of minimum working example. When you build this example you can find your problem impressively faster that adding slices of information in a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your calling code will use `__declspec (dllimport)` this trouble will be gone :)

```
#ifdef EXPORTING_SWC
  #define SWC_CALL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define SWC_CALL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Comment: where should I put it? on .h file or in the .exe file?

Comment: Edited my answer , this should be in header file

Comment: That was also on my actual code. Just too lazy to put it all here. I don't even know if my code is just like that or the revise of it, maybe.

Comment: Look at Joachim Pileborg words :) we need a SSCCE to assist  if your _consuming/application_ code contains __declspec (dllexport) (as I understand from your snippet ...) you must to initialize your static member also in the exe file

Comment: I already edited my post. I don't get what you guys still looking for. That is how my project looks like (but with absence of some other `class`es).

Comment: Can you make sure that when you compile your _exe_ the value for the SWC_CALL macro is __declspec (dllimport) ? my hunch is the ifndef part also applies in your exe build

Comment: will that remove the linking error I had if I got the right value of SWC_CALL while removing the redefinition of `SWC::SWC_Base::mouse` from .exe file?

Comment: Lets give it a try :) prima facia the answer is yep

Comment: @ShmilTheCat solved now.. I just #define _SWC_ before including the header file from the .exe file.

Comment: Groovy ! If i were you id define this macro only at the dll project file (this is the best practice). Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have added an anymous `namespace { }` around your definition (in case that you posted the real code) in the header file. Each anonymous namespace will translated to a compilation unit specific namespace by the compiler. Therefore you get always a new class in a new namespace.

To solve the problem you can either

- move the declaration, the defination, and all use to one source file
- use a named namespace

Comment: I just forgot to name the namespace 'SWC' in the header file. got to edit